# Combine calc() with attr() in CSS

Tags: css, css-calc

I was wondering whether I can combine the calc() function with the attr() function to achieve something like the following:

```
<div class="content" data-x="1">
    This box should have a width of 100px
</div>

<div class="content" data-x="2">
    This box should have a width of 200px
</div>

<div class="content" data-x="3">
    This box should have a width of 300px
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
    //Fallback. If no calc is supported, just leave it at 100px
    width: 100px;
}


.content[data-x]{
    // Multiply the width of the element by the factor of data-x
    width: calc(100px * attr(data-x));
}
```

The [draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) says it should work, but in my case (Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m and Firefox 25.0.1 ) it doesn't. There are two cases then:

1. I did it wrong
2. It is not supported yet

Whats the deal?

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/loupax/cQ8F4/)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Right now attr() is not supported by default in any major browser for any attributes other then "content". Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Comment: Here's an example with "content": http://jsfiddle.net/cQ8F4/2/

Comment: Yes not supported. You can do it not dynamic with css like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cQ8F4/3/ For the dynamic solution i would use javascript or jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/cQ8F4/4/

Comment: As of  19 May 2018 this answer is still mostly correct, but the linked documentation only states that support for `attr()` for properties other than `content` is experimental. I suggest referring to [the Can I use... page](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr) as it will likely be updated if / when browsers start to support this usage.

Answer (score 44):

There appears to be a way around it [using `var`s](http://jsfiddle.net/cQ8F4/54/)

```css
.content{
    --x: 1;
    width: calc(100px * var(--x));
    background: #f00;
}

[data-x="1"] { --x: 1; }
[data-x="2"] { --x: 2; }
[data-x="3"] { --x: 3; }

/*doesn't look like this works unfortunately
[data-x] { --x: attr(data-x); }
seems to set all the widths to some really large number*/
```

The commented out section would have been perfect, and this may be the very same reason your idea didn't work, but it seems css doesn't perform the nice automatic casting that you might be used to in javascript (`'2' * 3 //=6`).
`attr()` returns a string, not a number, and this can be seen by adding `.content:after { content:var(--x) }`; nothing gets printed, --x is a number, `content` accepts strings.

If there is some css function to cast I feel like that would be the key to this problem.

---

Looks like casting <sub>(well, interpreting)</sub> will be a thing in [CSS4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr), and it'll be as simple as

```
.content{
    width: calc(100px * attr(data-x number, 1));
    background: #f00;
}
```

To date, no browsers support even this experimental spec, but I'll update when it does.

Comment: This is pretty awesome, even without the attr() support!  It can allow definition of some really nice layouts!

Comment: FYI, IE does not support CSS variables, and Edge is slowly getting there. Most other browsers support them though! http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: Looking back at this and my comment that `[it] seems to set all the widths to some really large number`, it got me thinking that if CSS doesn't cast, it might be trying to use the string *as* a numbers. So I tried with [`data-x="&#x01;"`](http://jsfiddle.net/521x3had/) to be `1`, `&#x02;` for `2` et cetera, but the widths arent getting set at all. The browsers must have patched to not attempt to use string vars at all. I wonder if this would have worked in the past..

Comment: I hope is not too late.

For me this is also a valid answer, since attr tents to be dynamic, that still needs JS in order to set the value of that attribute. Then instead, we can set the style inline such as 

`element.setAttribute('style',\`"--x: ${x}"\`);`

Or in other hand modify a Style element with `textContent` in the same way.
That would works perfectly in browser which support css vars.

Comment: In addition we can cast the `calc` unit in that way:
`calc(1UNIT * (YOUR OPERATIONS) )` ex `calc(1px * 16/9 )`

Comment: can the element itself specify the var? `<div style="--x: 3;">`

Comment: No I don't think any sort of reflection or meta variables/templating will be available through css

Answer (score 31):

At the moment the attr() function isn't working in Chrome.

An almost as nice solution is to use CSS variables:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      :root {
         --module-size: 100px;
         --data-x:1; /* Default value */
       }

      .content{
          width: calc(var(--module-size) * var(--data-x));
          border: 1px solid;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content" style="--data-x:1">
        This box should have a width of 100px
    </div>

    <div class="content" style="--data-x:2">
        This box should have a width of 200px
    </div>

    <div class="content"  style="--data-x:3">
        This box should have a width of 300px
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!