# create stack of blocks with the number of blocks as the size of an array

Tags: css, angular, sass, scss-mixins

I need to have some stack of divs that are on top of each other. The number of blocks is defined by the length of a given array that is in my component,which is dynamic. For example if the array is sized 2 the result will be:
[image]

If the size of the array is 3 the result will be [image]

I understand that I need to loop through the number of blocks I want and
`transform: translate(-50% *(i), -50% * i)`
where i is the index of the for that starts with 1.
how I can achive this using scss/ css only ? How do I pass the variable in order to loop through it? Or there is another way that can be done ?

In my component I have an array , it can change it's size. The number of blocks has to be as the size of this array.
Thanks

Comment: You really can't without knowing how many elements there are.

Comment: In my component I have an array of elements , the stack has to be sized as the length of this array.

Comment: @Paulie_D check again I have edited the post

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for

Comment: You  better use negative margin...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63764705/8620333

Comment: can someone create a stackblitz with an example ?

Comment: not a blitz but a pen : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RwaQyyq to demonstrate idea & loop

Comment: thanks, I have managed to solve it witout sass loops