# calc css top in sass with css attr() function

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to do something like in in sass:

```
provider-details {
        position: absolute;
        top: calc( #{$speciality-widget-top-offset} + #{$speciality-n-provider-details-gap} + #{attr(data-speciality-widget-height)});
        left: auto;
        right: $provider-details-right-offset;
        bottom: $providers-details-bottom-offset;
        max-height: 715px;
    }
```

I tried this too:

```
top: $speciality-widget-top-offset + $speciality-n-provider-details-gap + attr(data-speciality-widget-height);
```

but nothing is working. is there a way to calculate `top` with css `attr()` function in `sass`?

Comment: what's wrong with it ?

Comment: with sass interpolation i get this `calc( 30px + 15px + attr(data-speciality-widget-height, px))`

Comment: and this with second approach `45pxattr(data-speciality-widget-height)` as output

Comment: ah I see, sadly that's invalid css. You can't use attr funcion inside calc currently. it might be a thing in CSS4

Answer (score 0):

so issue you have is that `attr(...)` inside calc is invalid CSS (might change later on in CSS4 as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40815884/3484498))

A workaround would be to change your html to replace your data attribute with an inline css variable like this:

```html
<div style="--speciality-widget-height: 2">
```

and use it like this:

```
top: calc(#{$speciality-widget-top-offset} + #{$speciality-n-provider-details-gap} + var(--speciality-widget-height));
```